# http status 500- null pointer Exception only on google chrome

Tags: servlets, runtime-error

I am using tomcat 7 and net beans IDE 7.3.1 for my project. My servlet program is working fine on Mozilla Firefox and Internet Explorer.but when i m running it on Google chrome it shows following error.

```
   HTTP Status 500 -

type Exception report

message description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

java.lang.NullPointerException
   Controller.CreateQuestion.doPost(CreateQuestion.java:200)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
Filters.logoutfilter.doFilter(logoutfilter.java:27)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.34 logs.

Apache Tomcat/7.0.34
```

Please help anybody,
thanks.

Comment: looks like the data posted is incorrect, resulting in a NPE.

Comment: I think this snippet is not enough to say something. Add please some code (.jsp that should be open instead of this error, a piece of controller which should catch your request, etc.)

Comment: i will explain in detail. one jsp page i.e. createquestion.jsp which takes data like type of question and its options and correct answers with question and its description. now one more field i have created on form which takes related image of that question if any.this field is not compulsory in this page.so if i am not taking any image for one of the question then also i can send whole data in database with the help of controller.its working fine by java program.its working in mozilla and IE. but why it is not working in chrome then??

Comment: here is the code for servlet to take imag parameter value and to set its value in table.

Comment: <input type="file" name="image" id="image" />  here is servlet code.       img = request.getParameter("image");                                                                     if (img.equals("")) {
                q.setIsimage(0);

            } else {
                q.setIsimage(1);
            }