# NullPointerException happens on chrome but no such prblem on IE

Tags: java, google-chrome, jsp

I just encountered a weird problem. I was writting a wel.jsp file which plays a role of showing content that queried from database. At first I just wrote some snippets as follows:

```
//the data are transfered from "result"
ArrayList<UserBean> al = (ArrayList)request.getAttribute("result");
```

as for result, it is achieved from LoginClServlet.java file. Its snippets are as follows:

```
//put al as "result" into request
request.setAttribute("result", al);
```

and because the user can go directly(illegally) without putting username to wel.jsp, al can point to null which will cause problem.

In order to solve that, I added a session into LoginClServlet.java file as follows:

```
//put al as "result" into request
request.setAttribute("result", al);

//put userName into session to avoid illegal login
request.getSession().setAttribute("userName", u);
```

then, in wel.jsp file, I firstly check if userName is null:

```
//prevent illegal login

String u = (String)session.getAttribute("myName");


if(u==null) {
    //go back
    response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
    return ;
}
....
ArrayList<UserBean> al = (ArrayList)request.getAttribute("result");
```

in this way, I think I correctly avoided illegal input. 
When I tried the code in IE, I got the result as I wished, however, when I tried it in Chrome(and I also cleared cookies in chrome) , I still got a error saying that

```
An exception occurred processing JSP page /wel.jsp at line 61
```

I dont know how to fix this problem. I tried to describe it clearly and hope someone could help me.

the stacktrace is as follows:

```
Stacktrace:] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.jsp.wel_jsp._jspService(wel_jsp.java:136)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:439)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2522)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2511)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

BTW I found a similar problem on this : [http status 500- null pointer Exception only on google chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21822352/http-status-500-null-pointer-exception-only-on-google-chrome)

Comment: Stacktrace and codesnippet please.

Comment: Hi, Stacktrace is added. the code is not very short, and I tried my best to describe it. I am pretty sure the problem lies in the code that I put in

Comment: How about doing some debugging to figure out what's in `u` when using chrome?

Comment: A shot in the dark - different handling of cookies? Check in both browsers' cookie managers.

Comment: @TomášM. correct. it is because of cookie. Chrome kept my prior input as cookie. Now I cleared the cookie and it works.

Comment: Good! I guessed it because I've been wrestling with the same kind of insane JSP heisenbugs :)

Comment: Do you have your Java code inside JSP file?

Comment: @NewUser already solved. It is because of cookies kept automatically by chrome

Comment: @LeonloveKaren: Glad you could resolve it.